# Deploy multiple asp.net application on single EC2 instance of AWS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to deploy one application having different database based on region 
i.e. application remains same but the database changes according to the url.

for example

1. for India database will be db_india
2. for Singapore database will be db_sg
3. for USA database will be db_usa

Hence I need to delpoy a application into 3 different subfolder on same instance so that there web.config can be different

So I need to know if there is any method other than FTP so that we can deploy application to subfolder or I can use any other method to accomplish this.

Comment: Zip and transfer over rdp?

Comment: @Crudler i already told i dont require ftp method

Comment: ??? rdp = remote desktop protocol. not ftp

Comment: @curdler its nearly same way method

Comment: only ways I ever got stuff up to my box were those two. theoretically you could also set up drop box folders an let them sync (but that might be messy as you wont know if something is half way done with the sync). Would be nicer if there was something more systemetised like with Azure, but nothing else I know of.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar currently using MS web deploy.

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy

It's a bit of a pain to set up, but once you do, you can deploy to your site directly from within Visual Studio. You can publish to multiple sites by importing or configuring them as different endpoints.